# mxGraph zoom to fit view

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

How to zoom mxGraph to fit in view on initial render?

I have set the width and height of the container to be 100%. I want to scale the the mxgraph rendered in the container to fit in the container. How can I do that?

```js
function addNodes(nodes, graph, parent) {
    // Needed to connect the edges
    const nodeData = new Object();
    nodes.forEach((node) => {
        nodeData[node.id] = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, node.title, 0, 0, 100, 20, 'defaultVertex;fillColor=' + (node.error ? 'red' : 'green'));
    })
    return nodeData;
}

function addEdges(edges, nodes, graph, parent) {
    edges.forEach((edge) => {
        graph.insertEdge(parent, null, '', nodes[edge.source], nodes[edge.target]);
    })
} 

export function mountGraph(containerName, data) {
    const container = document.getElementById(containerName);
    const graph = new mxGraph(container);

    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    const parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    const nodes = addNodes(data.nodes, graph, parent);
    addEdges(data.edges, nodes, graph, parent);
    const layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
    layout.execute(parent);
    graph.getModel().endUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Provide some code please

Comment: I have added a code snippet but not sure if it would be useful

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mxGraph.fit](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.fit) for that: `Scales the graph such that the complete diagram fits into <container> and returns the current scale in the view.`

Notice that if you call `fit` after calling your `mountGraph` function, 2 paints/renderings will be performed. The 1st one after the `graph.getModel().endUpdate()` call, and second one after the `graph.fit` call.

To avoid that, as we want to fit an initial graph prior to rendering, the documentation proposes to set mxGraphView.rendering to false prior to changing the model and do the rendering after the fit.

In the `mountGraph` function, this may be something like

```js
    graph.view.rendering = false;
    
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    ...
    graph.getModel().endUpdate();

    graph.fit();
    graph.view.rendering = true;
    graph.refresh();
```